# Rails 4: How to filter an ActiveRecord::Relation based on the presence of some string within an array field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

I am expanding the sample application of Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, which you can find here http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/. The objective of the tutorial is to create a twitter-like website, therefore some of the models are User, Micropost and Relationship, where the last one is intended to establish the relationships of follower and followed among the users (just like in twitter) and to define the logic for retrieveng microposts from the database according the user.

That being said, I want to expand the sample application adding the following functionality:
When writing a micropost, this can be retrieved either by all the user's followers by default or by specific followers whose user names are explicitly included in the content of the micropost, with each name preceded by @ symbol.

Example:

User ExampleUser posted two microposts:

micropost_1 with content "hello world" will appear in the micropost feed of every follower.

micropost_2 with content "hello world @john @peter" will appear only in peter's and john's micropost feeds (as long as peter and john are the names of actual users that follow ExampleUser).

In order to achieve this objective, so far I have done the following:

1) I added the field "receivers" of type text to the Micropost model through the console lines:

```
rails g migration AddReceiverToMicropost receivers:text
rake db:migrate
```

And then I added the following line to the Micropost model

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
serialize :receivers
```

This allows me to save an array in the receivers field thanks to the serialize functionality (for this I based in the following site: http://amberonrails.com/storing-arrays-in-a-database-field-w-rails-activerecord/)

Thus, I would be able to store a string array with the receivers' names for a given micropost.

2) Next, I tried to solve the problem of extracting the receivers' names from a micropost's content. So I went to the MicropostsController and created the following method:

```
private

    def get_receivers(content)
        receivers = []
        i = 0
        i0 = 0
        while i < content.length do
            i = content.index('@',i0)
            if i.nil?
                break
            else
                i0 = content.index(' ',i)
                if i0.nil?
                    unless i + 1 == content.length
                        receivers << content[i+1..-1]
                    end
                    break
                else
                    unless i + 1 == i0
                        receivers << content[i+1..i0-1]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        receivers
    end
```

and then I applied it withing the MicropostsController's create method:

```
    def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save          
        @micropost.update(receivers: get_receivers(@micropost.content)) #this line uses the get_receivers method to set the receivers field
        flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        @feed_items = []
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
end
```

The line followed by the comment is the added one.
So far this works properly.

3) Finnaly I tried to update the method that retrieves all the micropost feed of a user (properly signed-in) in order to implement the new functionality. The method is a class method called from_users_followed_by(user), defined in the Micropost model class, and this is the original code (as it appears in the tutorial):

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
   followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
   where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
      user_id: user.id)
end
```

This method is invoked by the feed method of User class, here is the code:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     .
     .
     .
    def feed    
        Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
    end
```

And finally, feed in turn is invoked within the home method of the StaticPagesController in response to a request of displaying the sites's homepage provided that a user is properly signed-in at the moment:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
        if signed_in?
            @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
            @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
        end
  end
```

So, you can see that the original self.from_users_followed_by(user) method retrieves all the user's followed users' microposts plus his own microposts. But in order to add the receivers filter layer, I updated it to this new version:

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    microposts = where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
      user_id: user.id)

    microposts_filtered = []

    microposts.each do |m|
        if m.receivers.nil? or m.receivers.length == 0 or m.receivers.include? user.name
            microposts_filtered << m
        end
    end
    microposts_filtered
end
```

As you can see, my attempt was to manually filter the microposts of the microposts Relation returned by the where method and pass the approved ones into the array microposts_filtered. I thought this was going to work, but a problem arises in the StaticPagesController's home method in the line

```
@feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

and this is that an array has no method called paginate, which is a method of ActiveRecord::Relation class. That's the reason for my title question: how can I add this receivers filter layer in the where method in order to keep the Relation as output, since an array does not allow pagination?

Sorry for the long exposition of the problem but I did it this way for the sake of understanding. I would like to know how I could solve this problem or if there are other better approaches to achieve the same results in a better fashion. Improvements for any part of the whole problem (such as a better method to get the user names from a micropost's content) are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using sqlite for development and PostgreSQL in production (because I am deploying to Heroku)

Comment: You can use a regex instead of that big `#get_receivers` method. For instance: `/@.+?\b/`

Comment: Using different databases in development and production is your first mistake, for your own good, please stop doing that. Start developing on top of PostgreSQL and then get rid of that `serialize` stuff, then this becomes much easier.